# Android: AsyncTask with AlarmManager and Service

Tags: android

I want to post  JSON string with HttpURLConnection api to the localhost server(WAMP) periodically every 60 seconds to be inserted in the database. Therefore, I am executing MyAsyncTask from the timer method. Would it be better approach to implement that with help of AlarmManager and Service or it is sufficient for my purposes?

I appreciate any help.

PostData class:

```
 package com.bustracker;

    import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;

    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Handler;

        public class PostData {
            String jSONString;
            Handler handler = new Handler();

            public PostData(String jSONString) {
                super();
                this.jSONString = jSONString;
            }

            public String getjSONString() {
                return jSONString;
            }

            public void setjSONString(String jSONString) {
                this.jSONString = jSONString;
            }

      public void timer() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean run = true;
            while (run) {
               handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       new MyAsyncTask().execute(jSONString);
                   }
               }, 5000);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

            class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    try {
                        //This is the ip address of my laptop wifi because I am running the app in my device and I want to send the data to the localhost server(WAMP). 
                        URL myUrl = new URL("http://192.168.127.56/webservice"); 
                        HttpURLConnection myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl
                                .openConnection();
                        myConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        myConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                        myConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                        myConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                        myConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                        myConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                                "application/json");
                        myConnection.connect();
                        // create data output stream
                        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                                myConnection.getOutputStream());
                        // write to the output stream from the string
                        wr.writeBytes(jSONString);
                        wr.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;

                }

            }

        }
```

The passed JSON string to the PostData class:

```
    {
      "latitude":41.86907321,
      "longitude":16.66542435,
      "formatted":"22.04.2015 11:11:00",
       "route":4
    }
```

**Edit:**

this code is bein called in the onChanedLocation from the inner class "MyLocationListern" of the MainActivity:

```
        String jSONString = convertToJSON(pLong, pLat, formatted);
        PostData sender = new PostData(jSONString);             
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostData.class);
        PendingIntent pintent3 = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent3, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm3 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        // for 30 mint 60*60*1000
        alarm3.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                1000, pintent3);

        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), PostData.class));
```

The new PostData class with IntentService:

```
package com.bustracker;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;

public class PostData extends IntentService {
    String jSONString;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public PostData(String jSONString) {
        super("some");
        this.jSONString = jSONString;
    }

    public String getjSONString() {
        return jSONString;
    }

    public void setjSONString(String jSONString) {
        this.jSONString = jSONString;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(jSONString);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                //This is the ip address of my laptop wifi because I am running the app in my device and I want to send the data to the localhost server(WAMP). 
                URL myUrl = new URL("http://192.168.x.x/webservice"); 
                HttpURLConnection myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl
                        .openConnection();
                myConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                myConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                myConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                myConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                myConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                myConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "application/json");
                myConnection.connect();
                // create data output stream
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                        myConnection.getOutputStream());
                // write to the output stream from the string
                wr.writeBytes(jSONString);
                wr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

    }



}
```

Comment: As a tip, you are creating a whole new Thread just for the purpose of sleeping. You can accomplish this better using handler.postDelayed instead of handler.post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first we create a service like this

```
public class ChatSevice extends IntentService{

    public ChatSevice() {
        super("Some");
    }



    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //this is asynk task class
        new ChatConnect(ChatSevice.this).execute();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




}
```

and now call this service like this way

```
Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, ChatSevice.class);
        PendingIntent pintent3 = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent3, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm3 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        // for 30 mint 60*60*1000
        alarm3.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                1000, pintent3);

        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ChatSevice.class));
```

Comment: First: what is `cal` because it says `cal cant be resolved`? Second: I am getting this error at this line`Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, PostData.class);` this error `The constructor Intent(MainActivity.myLocationListener, Class<PostData>) is undefined` since I am invoking the last part from my MainActivity class.

Comment: cal is  a object of calender like this ..........             Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

Comment: Thanks for your answer and what about the second error at this line `Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, PostData.class);`  I am getting `The constructor Intent(MainActivity.myLocationListener, Class<PostData>) is undefined` since I am invoking the last part from my MainActivity class.

Comment: And where can I pass the JSON string when I call the service? I want to pass JSON string to the PostData class.

Comment: use this Intent(activity.this, PostData.class);  instead of Intent(this, PostData.class);

Comment: in service class you can use asynk task to pass data

Comment: I have this code above the service calling part `    String jSONString = convertToJSON(pLong, pLat, formatted);
    PostData sender = new PostData(jSONString); sender.timer()` which I used before to pass data how can I do it in ur case?

Comment: you call this your asynk task   new MyAsyncTask().execute(jSONString); instead of  of code   new ChatConnect(ChatSevice.this).execute(); in chatclass

Comment: I am facing the problem that the compiler is not being called this method `onStartCommand`  and it is sticking at this line `startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), PostData.class));`  Please take a look at my updated question I have edited the code with your approach.

Comment: r You  declare service in manifest file like    <service android:name=".chatservice" />

Comment: I did not but I did it after reading ur comments. Sorry to bother u again but I am getting now the following error: `Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.bustracker.PostData has no zero argument constructor` after adding the receiver in the Mainfest file.

Comment: did you use  constructor like me for service      public ChatSevice() {
        super("Some");
    }                    this should be empty no parameter

Comment: but if it is empty how can I pass the JSON String from the onLocationChanged method in the inner class of the MainActivity  to the PostData method? `String jSONString = convertToJSON(pLong, pLat, formatted); PostData sender = new PostData(jSONString); Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostData.class); ...............`

Comment: Ok I changed my constructor to zero parameter constructor but I still dont know how can I interlink  the calling part with the PostData class to pass JSON string to it.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, i would use the alarm manager. That's what its for.

It is none of my business, but you should keep in mind that a request over the internet once every minute will drain your battery.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Service for your purpose and for every 60 seconds, you need not use Alarm Manager.
Because Service is providing intent filter functionality to call service after every Minute.

for that you have to write following code when you will register your service:

```
ServiceDemo serviceDemo = new ServiceDemo();
        IntentFilter s_intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
        s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);

        registerReceiver(serviceDemo , s_intentFilter);
```

Service will execute after every 60 seconds using this code.

Comment: please would you implement my code with the use of Service because I dont know where to put the MyAsyncTask in this approach?