# Intentservice not working properly

Tags: android, sqlite, intentservice

I have an activity, where a user selects date and time, and the date is entered into the sqlite database. From the activity, I am starting an IntentService like below

```
Intent intents = new Intent (this,AlarmIntentService.class);
    startService(intents);
```

In the intentservice, I am comparing those data from sqlite database to the current system time, and broadcasting an alarm.

It works fine, when I call the intentservice, first time, with one entry into the database. But, when the user inserts the second data into the sqlite database, and starts the Intentservice, it doesn't work.

Is there anyway to update the passed intentservice with the new data?

The intentservice onhandleintent is described below

```
 final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    final SqliteController db = new SqliteController(getApplicationContext());
    List<Greetings> greetings = db.getAllGreetings();
    int k = db.getGreetingsCount();
    String p = String.valueOf(k);
    Log.d("p", p);    
if (db.getGreetingsCount() >= 0) {
        do {
            for (Greetings g : greetings) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                d1 = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                d2 = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                d3 = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                t1 = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                t2 = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                t3 = cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
                if (t3 == 1) {
                    t4 = "PM";
                } else {
                    t4 = "AM";
                }

                tc = String.valueOf(t1) + " : " + t2 + " " + t4;

                d = String.valueOf(d3) + "-" + String.valueOf(d2 + 1) + "-" + String.valueOf(d1);
                cdt = d + "\t" + tc;
                time = g.getTime();
                date = g.getDate();
                phone = g.getPhoneNumber();
                msg = g.getMessage();
                id = g.getID();
                dnt = date + "\t" + time;

                if (dnt.equals(cdt)) {
                    Intent aint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);

                    aint.putExtra("msg", msg);
                    aint.putExtra("phone", phone);
                    aint.putExtra("id", id);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, aint, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                    showNotification();
                    db.deleteGreetings(g);
                }

            }
            k = db.getGreetingsCount();

        } while (k != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for you service call using intent filter.

[Android: AsyncTask with AlarmManager and Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29818271/android-asynctask-with-alarmmanager-und-service/29818497#29818497)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving all your declarations out of the loop. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**1º create a file Class:**

```
public class ClassAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
       Log.i("BroadCast Alarm", "do anything");         
    }
}
```

**2º Register your *Broadcast* in *ANDROIDMANIFEST* file :**

```
<receiver android:name=".ClassAlarm" >
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="broadCastAlarm" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**3º Your start and stop functions alarm**
Your ***AlarmManager*** and  ***PendingIntent*** must be global variable.

```
private static AlarmManager alarm       = null;
private static PendingIntent    pintent     = null;


public static void startAlarm(Context context)
{
    if (pintent == null && alarm == null)
    {

        Intent startIntent = new Intent("broadCastAlarm");
        pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, startIntent, 0);
        alarm = (AlarmManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        //wait 10000ms
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                    10000, pintent);
    }

}

public static void stop_alarm(Context context)
{
    if (alarm != null && pintent != null)
    {
        pintent.cancel();
        alarm.cancel(pintent);
        alarm = null;
        pintent = null;
    }
}
```